# Probability limit in Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes

[image]

In the problem above, I solved all questions but the last one confuses me. I can see that state 5 can only lead to state 1, hence it is clear that the probability and the limit of the probability is equal to 1. What does have $r$ have to do here? How does it influence the limit? am I understanding the expression wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It asks about a multi-step transition, the probabilities are not always 1. For example the probability of going from 5 to 1 in 6 steps is zero.

Comment: I see that! So it has to do with periodicity. Thank you I didn't think of that